# Calling WCF Service - 202 Accepted Returned

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I've written a WCF service, which works fine in Visual Studio running locally.

However, when I install the service on a server running IIS 7 and try calling it (using the same code, with only the URL changed), the service returns 202 Accepted rather than the expected response.

I've searched the internet trying to find why this is being returned, but can't find anything.  I'm sure this is a configuration issue, but currently I'm at a loss.

Can anyone help?